# Why can I remove certain files in Cygwin but not Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

I have a folder that contains files I have compiled in .NET (however this question could easily apply to a non-programmer's folder too, e.g. containing word documents or whatever.)

When I try to clear it out using the Command Prompt:

```
del /F /S *
```

Then I get an "Access is Denied" on a certain file. This is definitely not due to security so it must be a lock.

However when I use Cygwin I am able to delete it:

```
$ rm -r *
```

So what is Cygwin doing that is special. Can I emulate this some how from the regular command prompt?

*By the way this happens enough times 100+ so that it isn't a fluke that the file got unlocked before I opened Cygwin. Definitely Cygwin is able to unlock it somehow but regular Command Prompt cannot do it.*

Comment: It could be due to security. Are you running the Windows command prompt as administrator? That might be significant, depending on the files you are trying to delete.

Comment: Yes running Windows command prompt as admin. Would be interesting to know what cygwin does differently under the bonnet. Maybe it goes in at a lower level to delete the file.